# MariaDB I/O Limit

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, iops

I have a server with MariaDB 10.6.
The `mysqld` process uses 100% of DSK with very high I/O.

I tried to set these values but it didn't have any affect:

```
innodb_io_capacity = 100
innodb_io_capacity_max = 100
```

[look at `atop` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNvh7.png)

Any solution?

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size?  How much RAM do you have?  How much data in the database?  What long-running queries do you have?  Seriously, these questions are more likely to get to the bottom of the I/O problem.

Comment: Thanks! There is any way to limit the IOPS not matter what the queries? Just slow down their speed by IOPS limit.

Comment: If you are worried about being charged for IOPS, then you need to revise the configuration of the queries to cut back on the number of IOPs. On the other hand, if the 100% is lowered to 50%, the queries will take twice as long; I seen no benefit in that.

Comment: @RickJames I dotn care about that because the queries so heavy and do 300 MB/s of read, without stop. So we have to limit that. It is just a customer who taking 100% of IOPS, so we want to limit his Mysql IOPS.

Comment: And the way to make them less heavy is to rewrite them and/or add better indexes.  There is no tunable to make them less heavy.